# What is ArrayReduce function in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: list-manipulation

Stephen Wolfram and others are discussing functions in Wolfram Language for working with arrays in episode on YouTube Live CEOing Ep 385: ArrayReduce & Insertion Design Review for Wolfram Language, but I couldn't find any reference to the function ArrayReduce anywhere on the Internet. How can I find its description and lay my hands upon it to play with it and to know it better, to include it into my version of Mathematica 12.1. It's definitely absent there!
The reference to the episode:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8GVpmIZrR5g&ab_channel=Wolfram
4:00

Comment: These talks are generally using not released versions, so no surprise you can't find it.